# Can I add an ftp folder to flex project in flexbuilder3?

Tags: ftp, flexbuilder

I have some config files (.xml's) used by my flex app sitting on remote servers.  I would like to be able to modify them in flex builder along with the local app files.  Ideally I could add a folder to my project that was the ftp folders.  If this is not possible, does anyone have a good idea for how to manage changes to these remote files.  Currently I download them from the ftp, make changes, upload them back and debug the app which is a pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess there is a plugin for Eclipse to do exactly what you like, and that should install into Flex Builder as its built on eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up installing RSE plugin:

http://www.venukb.com/2007/06/06/how-to-browse-remote-files-in-eclipse-ide/